# Как выполнить задачу в кроне?

Tags: php, api, cron

Есть код АПИ

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.travelpayouts.com/v2/prices/month-matrix?currency=RUS&origin=MOW&destination=LED&show_to_affiliates=true&month=2017-12-13&token=******");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: *******"));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$products=json_decode($response,true);
?>

<table id='example2' class='display'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Дата вылета     </th>
            <th> Цена, р.</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
<?php foreach ($products['data'] as $destination => $data) {

echo"<td>";
echo $data['depart_date']  ;
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo $data['value']  ;
echo"</td>"; echo"</tr>"; 
  }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Необходимо получаемые данные echo $data['value'] и  echo $data['depart_date']  сохранять каждые 30 минут в файл text.txt и вытащить и вставить в таблицу. Дуб дубом. Спасибо

P.S код сииииильно грузит сервер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сама команда для Cron `wget -O /dev/null script.php >/dev/null 2>&1`
Что б массив в файл записать используйте `json_encode()` например, а для извлечения `json_decode()`, для записи в файл `file_put_contents()` и для чтения `file_get_contents()`

Лучше разделить код на 2 файла. Первый для записи. Второй для чтения.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.travelpayouts.com/v2/prices/month-matrix?currency=RUS&origin=MOW&destination=LED&show_to_affiliates=true&month=2017-12-13&token=****");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: *****"));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
file_put_contents('text.txt', $response);
?>
```

Его ставим на Cron. А этот открываем для чтения.

```
<table id='example2' class='display'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Дата вылета </th>
<th>Цена, р.</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<?php 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('text.txt'), true);
for ($i=0; $i < count($data['data']); $i++) { 
echo"<td>";
echo $data['data'][$i]['depart_date']  ;
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo $data['data'][$i]['value']  ;
echo"</td>"; echo"</tr>";
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Код проверен. Работает.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Удалите пожалуйста из ответа Token. С уважением

Comment: @Arcadiy удалил

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Дениc вот у меня нет доступа к серверной части, а если все тоже но чисто на php без крона как бы это выглядело?

Comment: @Arcadiy можно использовать сервис который будет запускать скрипт по расписанию, я такими не пользовался, но вот первый что попался в поиске http://cronjob.ru/  просто укажите путь до файла, то что я писал для Cron не нужно указывать, просто в формате http://site.ru/script.php И график запуска укажите 30 минут.

Comment: @Дениc мне один человек дал кусок кода к моему коду но не сказал как их совместить. Может вы знаете? Вот именно к моему вопросу.  $recivedDataArray = array(....); //То что с АПИ получили
$toCache = serialize($recivedDataArray);
file_put_contents ("cache/".time()."_cache", $toCache);
file_put_contents ("cache/last_cache", $toCache);

Comment: @Arcadiy у вас данные с API приходят в Json формате, нет смысла переводить в начале в массив, а уже потом записывать через serialize в файл, а потом снова преобразовывать. Уже и так я сразу записал, без лишних телодвижений. Ну а вторая часть кода, это что  с каждым запросом создавался файл с данными и именем файла в виде времени. Но как я понял, данные там обновляются не быстро, зачем создавать копии данных?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70301/discussion-between-arcadiy-and-).